# table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it; needs after/row level query

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

How to rewrite a trigger to avoid the error **"BB_BASKET is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"**

Homework instructions: Create a trigger named BB_SALESUM_TRG that updates the BB_SALES_SUM accordingly when an order is confirmed or the ORDERPLACED column in the BB_BASKET table is updated to 1.

Been looking for solutions for this issue while not changing my homework assignment which indicates the query must be an AFTER trigger as the inventory has to be updated after the order was confirmed. Other SO suggestions are to change the AFTER to a BEFORE or INSERT, but BEFORE trigger would incorrectly update the inventory before confirmation and an INSERT cannot be used with a row-level trigger. Other suggestions to avoid triggers altogether are fine for real-world but not for homework specifically on triggers.

A statement level trigger may avoid the issue, but I cannot use my WHEN clause with a statement level trigger and I think I need the WHEN or my code will update the table regardless of quantity.

Adding a pragma autonomous transaction does not seem to get rid of the error

Other similar code in my homework book use AFTER with a SELECT statement in a cursor with no problem, so I don't think it's the SELECT statement in the cursor giving me grief.

```
CREATE TABLE BB_SALES_SUM (
product_id VARCHAR2(30) PRIMARY KEY,
total_sales NUMBER(8,2),
total_qty NUMBER(10),
OrderPlaced number(1)
);

Set ServerOutput On;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bb_salessum_trg
AFTER UPDATE OF orderplaced ON bb_basket
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(OLD.orderplaced <> 1 AND NEW.orderplaced = 1)
DECLARE
CURSOR basketitem_cur IS
   SELECT idbasket, total, quantity, orderplaced
   FROM bb_basket
   WHERE idbasket=:NEW.idbasket;
BEGIN
   FOR basketitem_rec in basketitem_cur LOOP
    UPDATE bb_sales_sum
    SET total_qty = basketitem_rec.quantity
    WHERE product_id = basketitem_rec.idbasket;
END LOOP;
END;
/

UPDATE bb_basket SET orderplaced = 1 WHERE idbasket = 14
```

Comment: *"Other suggestions to avoid triggers altogether are fine for real-world but not for homework specifically on triggers."* Yep, this is a classic example of a homework trigger.

Comment: yeah @APC the amount of times I have to say "I know this doesn't make sense and I'll never do it this way at work, but I need to do it this way for homework" makes me value CS as a major slightly less every semester

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about the logic of the problem. `bb_sales_sum.total_qty` is a total: that is, it is the sum of all the items sold. Your trigger does not calculate a total, so (if it executed) the outcome would be wrong: `bb_sales_sum.total_qty` would be set to the value of the item in the last basket, not the sum of the item sold.

Reading the question carefully we will see that it gives a nudge in the right direction:

> updates the BB_SALES_SUM accordingly when an order is confirmed or the ORDERPLACED column in the BB_BASKET table is updated to 1.

The trigger should only be updating the sum, not overwriting it. Let's try this.

Note: this looks wrong - `product_id = :new.idbasket` - but you haven't posted a complete set of tables or sample data. Also you haven't specified how *"an order is confirmed"*. So I'm going to assume your filtering logic is correct. You may have to tweak it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bb_salessum_trg
AFTER UPDATE OF orderplaced ON bb_basket
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(OLD.orderplaced <> 1 AND NEW.orderplaced = 1)
BEGIN

    UPDATE bb_sales_sum
    SET total_qty = total_qty + :new.quantity
    WHERE product_id = :new.idbasket;

END;
/
```